# Design Sketch for Video Streaming Platform

Tags: architecture

My friend and I are scoping out building a paid video streaming platform (think very small, local Netflix). I've done software engineering for around 5 years, but I've never worked with streaming video to devices.

This will be a small scale streaming service: few videos would be available through the service, and its user population would mostly live in the same area. I'm hoping this means I can worry less about CDNs.

Anyway, the components I think I'll need to worry about are:

- File hosting
- Transcoding for different devices & qualities and streaming
- Account sign up/in/out
- Payments

I'm most confused about the transcoding and streaming, but I'd be happy to hear I'm missing other large elements of this problem.

**I do have a few specific questions:**

- Is AWS Elemental overkill here? Is there a simpler/cheaper way to get good quality videos to stream to any device size?
- What should my concerns around DRM be? I know you can add it to files before streaming them to ensure pirates don't steal content, but I'm not sure that our risk of piracy will be high.
- Do you guys use any services or frameworks that make accounts, payments, and file upload extremely easy to set up?

So far, I am the crew on this project, so I'd like to take every off-the-shelf solution I can find.

I realize I'm asking a lot here, but any guidance is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look for a cheap CDN and embad the links in a wordpress app.
aws and other providers going to be way more expensive